# Validação do próprio dado que inseri no campo (limite de caracteres)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testes, automatização

Suponhamos que tenho um campo que possui limite de **15 caracteres**.

No meu **teste** eu adiciono **16 caracteres**.

Como faço para validar que foram inseridos somente **15 caracteres** no campo?

```
browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget']")).sendKeys("1236767676786983");

WebElement campoID = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget']"));

String texto = campoID.getText();
assertEquals("123676767678698", texto);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Normalmente utilizamos getText() para a maioria dos elementos, mas para o "input" o texto é mantido na estrutura da página de forma diferente, ele fica sob o o atributo "value".

Então você deve usar o método "getAttribute" passando o atributo "value" capturar o texto do input.

Dessa forma:

```
String texto = campoID.getAttribute("value");
```

Para a validação da quantidade de caracteres a melhor é fazer o assert da quantidade de caracteres não do texto:

Ficando assim:

```
assertEquals(15, texto.length())
```

Para ficar mais legível você pode adicionar uma mensagem indicando a validação que esta fazendo.

```
assertEquals("O tamanho do texto esperado é ", 15, texto.length())
//A resposta será: "O tamanho do texto esperado é (15) was (16)" 
//Caso o resultado seja falso.
```

Comment: Imart, obrigado pelo retorno! Tentei, mas o teste retorna erro! Poderia me ajudar?

`browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget']")).sendKeys("1236767676786983");
WebElement campoID = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget']"));
String texto = campoID.getText();
assertEquals(15, texto.length());`

`Erro: Expected :15
Actual   :0`

No entanto eu preenchi o campo com caractere!

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Estevão, editei a resposta com o que precisa para rodar esse teste. Da um ok se deu certo!

Comment: Imart, agradeço o retorno!

No entanto, continua dando Expected :2
Actual   :0 ....

O que será que pode ser?

browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget']")).sendKeys("1236767676786983"); WebElement campoID = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget']")); String texto = campoID.getAttribute("value"); assertEquals(15, texto.length());

Comment: Poderia me auxiliar

Comment: Cara, verifica se o xPath que você tá usando tá correto, se sim tenta da um clique fora do elemento, pode ser no label do próprio elemento mas tenta clicar fora do input. Isso deve da certo, se não, procura no html onde tá o valor que vc digitou e manda aqui. usa a função o incpecionar do browser.

Comment: Imart, vou verificar! Estou em viagem. Assim que retornar já valido! Obrigado desde já!